# Writing a custom dropout layer in Keras

Tags: neural-network, keras

I am still learning Keras, and am learning the various components of it. I am having a hard time writing a custom layer. I thought of the following, for the sake of an exercise. I want to write a custom inverted dropout layer, like described in slide 77 of http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2017/cs231n_2017_lecture7.pdf, except I want to drop with probability p, but divide by some other number (p1 say) instead of p when doing the dropout inversion. I have 2 options

1) Write the code exactly as is in the lecture slides. This is easy to do, but I do not know how to exclude the layer at test time.

2) Option 1 is a bad idea, , because I am re-writing a lot of code which we already have. I thought of using the dropout layer, but I am not sure how to modify another layer's results directly. https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/core.py#L78 shows that the results are calling Theano's backend to perform this task.

Could you please describe the best way to achieve this

Comment: Could you solve this?

Comment: Yes, it turned out to be rather straightforward. Sorry, I should have deleted the post

Comment: @Sid Could you please share your implementation ?